# iPhone not asking to store passwords

Tags: iphone, ios, password, bug

I’m running the latest iOS available (15.5) and my iPhone 13 is not asking if I want it to keep my login details in the “password vault”.

Actually, sometime, for some websites I’m asked, but for a whole bunch of others, it not.

May I had done some configuration that leading to this behavior? If yes, how can I revert?

Comment: Settings > Passwords > AutoFill Passwords. If AutoFill is enabled and you are still experiencing the lack of browsers forced retention. This would be website specific. The browser isn't detecting information related to a password. Then look at Settings > Safari>Request Desktop Websites[on], if the desktop version isn't producing the option to store password, it would be the website itself. Go back to your passwords and click the + icon on the top right. Individually enter the credentials you'd like to be prompted for AutoFill.